# C# XML Deserializing with NULL nodes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am trying to de-serialize an XML to an object MyClass. The XML is here:

```
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <var1 Type="Numeric">0.91766552047165573</var1>
      <var2 Type="Numeric">8</var2>
      <var3 Type="Numeric">11</var3>
      <var4 Type="Numeric">12</var4>
      <var5 Type="Numeric">0</var5>
      <var6 Type="Numeric">0.02</var6>
      <var7 Type="Financial" Currency="USD">7.0589655420896529</var7>
</MyClass>
```

And the code block below.

```
private string SerializeXml(string xml)
        {
            var _xml = @xml;
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
            using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                MyClass myClass = (MyClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Class declaration is below where I attempt to deserialize the class object

```
    [XmlRoot("MyClass")]
    [Serializable]
            public class MyClass
            {
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("var1")]
                public DataValue var1 { get; set; }
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("var2")]
                public DataValue var2 { get; set; }
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("var3")]
                public DataValue var3 { get; set; }
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("var4")]
                public DataValue var4 { get; set; }
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("var5")]
                public DataValue var5 { get; set; }
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("var6")]
                public DataValue var6 { get; set; }
                [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("var7")]
                public DataValue var7 { get; set; }
            }
```

Comment: How is `MyClass` declared?

Comment: Sorry about that description has been updated

Comment: you have another MyClass node under the root, that might be why. try removing it and only have one MyClass as root.

Comment: Thanks Selman, I think you might be right, let me try that

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename or remove MyClass Node as it's defined twice in xml

Comment: Thanks Bhanu, I'll give that a try. Not too sure how to remove the node as of yet, but I'll try a few things

Comment: Hi Bhanu, I got the following exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <MyClassCalc xmlns=''> was not expected. When changing the root attribute node to MyClassCalc

Comment: May you send me xml which you are trying with

Comment: <MyClassCalc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyClass>
    <var1 Type="Numeric">0.91766552047165573</var1>
    <var2 Type="Numeric">8</var2>
    <var3 Type="Numeric">11</var3>
    <var4 Type="Numeric">12</var4>
    <var5 Type="Numeric">0</var5>
    <var6 Type="Numeric">0.02</var6>
    <var7Type="Financial" Currency="USD">7.0589655420896529</var7>
  </MyClass>
</MyClassCalc>

Comment: I got the error to clear now by changing the [XmlRoot("MyClass")] to [XmlRoot("MyClassCalc")] above the declaration, but I still get NULL values

Comment: @Falcone80 You should not post code via a comment. Maybe use an upload sevice like gist & post only a link or edit your question if directly related, or even maybe move the convo to gitter

Answer (score 0):

The deserialization did not recognize the data type I was using, I converted all numeric members of my class to double and it deserialized correctly